# Is there a way to de-register a InitiatedBy Flow in Junit

Tags: corda

I have tests where during the `setUp` there's a registration of all initiatedFlow to the nodes.

But at the same time, I want to dynamically de-register some initiatedBy flows and register it with a mock responder flow.

Comment: Why do you need to deregister? Can't you just register a different flow as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49749451/how-to-mock-a-responder-flow-in-corda?

Comment: In the same @_Test, I want to assert some facts as a result of the real responder flow. Then de-register and register with a mocked one. The current workaround I have is to remove the central auto-registration from the @_Before setup, and in every test register manually by defining which responder to add to the nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Successive calls to `registerInitiatedFlow` override each other.

For example, if you do:

```
node.registerInitiatedFlow(FlowA::class.java)
node.registerInitiatedFlow(FlowB::class.java)
```

Then `FlowB` will be used as the responder.

Comment: As long as the responder share the same initiatingFlow, it overrides each other?

Comment: Yep, it's undocumented behaviour but it seems that way.

Comment: Hey joel it doesnt seem to work when i have Mock1Responder and Mock2Responder, the second supposed to override the 1st. Refer to https://github.com/adrian-soon/obligation-cordapp/blob/50cc897905b1f2231fef3f59b71b71d81aae7121/kotlin-source/src/test/kotlin/net/corda/examples/obligation/flows/IssueObligationTests.kt#L41